# SVG image blur on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I am trying to blur an image on Firefox using the SVG technique proposed [here](http://css-plus.com/2012/03/gaussian-blur/).

However this very simple example is not working on Firefox (I am version 25) [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mottalrd/jLW3D/).

HTML

```
<img class="blur" src="http://css-plus.com/examples/2012/03/gaussian-blur/i/fence.jpg" />
```

CSS

```
.blur {
    filter: url("http://d2oujmlvvb0w9i.cloudfront.net/images/v4/blur.svg#blur")    
}
```

Any help?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox does not support cross origin filters for HTML content. From the relevant blog post:

> The SVG elements being used for clipping, masking, and so forth can be
>   loaded from an external document, as long as that document comes from
>   the same origin as the HTML document to which it's applied.

Answer (score 7):

I used this [POST](http://demosthenes.info/blog/534/Crossbrowser-Image-Blur) for creating blur effect but I added coding base64.

```
img.blur { 
    filter: blur(3px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    -moz-filter: blur(3px);
    -o-filter: blur(3px);
    -ms-filter: blur(3px);
    filter: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+DQoJPGZpbHRlciBpZD0iYmx1ciI+DQoJCTxmZUdhdXNzaWFuQmx1ciBzdGREZXZpYXRpb249IjMiIC8+DQoJPC9maWx0ZXI+DQo8L3N2Zz4=#blur);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3rs8q/)

Code for SVG file

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="blur">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" />
    </filter>
</svg>
```