# CSS cross browser filter blur not working on Firefox

Tags: css, svg, filter, cross-browser, blur

i made a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jR6rM/2/) , i'm trying applying blur to a div, in Chrome everythings ok, but in Firefox it won't work.

I'm using `SVG` trying making blur cross browser but pfff it seems something is wrong, do you have any clue?

Comment: That image looks pretty naughty when blurred.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401219/svg-image-blur-on-firefox/20404052#comment30503998_20404052

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok sorry i fixed, it was `filter:blur('#svgBlur');` to `filter:url('#svgBlur');`