# Svg for blur image

Tags: html, css, svg, blur, svg-filters

I have `div` with 2 `background: img(url), img(url())...` centered on screen. Need to make the image (well, both overlayed) blury using svg (NOT CSS# filter prop)
Somehow These not working: (blur.svg file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
 <svg width="1" height="1" version="1.1"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
      <filter id="bluring">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2 3" />
      </filter>
   </defs>
</svg>
```

html:

```
.svgflt { background-color: orangered; backgroung: url(...);  
              filter: url(blur.svg#bluring);
...
 <div class="svgflt">  </div>
```

Comment: Your svg have no size ? Please refer to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/vuTqY/ (source: jalbertbowdenii)

Comment: also I hope this `backgroung` is a typo.

Comment: using pure SVG (as in the cyrbil's demo) of course works. But if you want to show the image as the `div`s background then I think there is a cross-browser problem here. In fact the code above should work in ***FireFox***. I've tried a simple demo in Internet Explorer but it does not work. It also does not work in webkit-based browsers. However you can use the `-webkit-filter` CSS feature instead. In conclusion you would be stuck at how to make the code work in Internet Explorer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401219/svg-image-blur-on-firefox/20404052#20404052

Comment: @Anon your demo does not work in Intenet Explorer. That's in fact the OP's problem. (his code should work in FireFox, and with the `filter` CSS property, it should work in webkit-based browsers but for Internet Explorer, there is not a solution).

Comment: For IE you can use filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='3');

Comment: filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='3'); won't work in IE10 or above.

Comment: @Anon DX filters seem to be obsolete so better not rely on them http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801215(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: obviously, is TYpo about bg, I mean bo problem cuzed in there

Comment: @King King, how about canvas+JS http://jsfiddle.net/rt5tymkv/ ?

Comment: @Anon that's a totally different thing. The `<div>` in fact can contain many things (not just its background), using `SVG` or `filter` CSS can even blur the whole `<div>`. It's pity that there is no way to solve it in IE. Instead of using Canvas, you can just use pure SVG (without using `<div>`) like this http://jsfiddle.net/vuTqY/225/ . Also the code in your demo seems to be complicated. For bluring I think we can just use some simple *Gaussian Blur Matrix*, loop through the points and update each.

Comment: @King King, our life will be easier without IE))))

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling. you have written "`backgroung`"

Also, This link might help:
http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_fegaussianblur.asp

See if you writing the code right.